Azure "Copy files over SSH" task fails to connect to remote machine - even though I can manually access it
I'm a little confused: I've got two Ubuntu 22 VMs in the same network, one only hosting an Azure Build Agent and the other one is supposed to be the live VM. Both have SSH configured.
Using Azure DevOps, I created a pipeline that uses the "Copy files over SSH" task to copy files from a repo to the live VM. However, that task fails with this error message (this is everything is gives me, even if I turn on "Enable System Diagnostics"):
Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: All configured authentication methods failed..

So then I connected to the BuildAgent VM via SSH, created my a file containing my private key and opened an SSH connection from this VM to the live VM. To my surprise, that works.
Any idea why the manual connection works, but the one created by Azure DevOps fails?

How did you configure the SSH Service Connection used by the "Copy files over SSH" task?

With the exact user that I used to connect to it manually & pasting in the private key. Then left the password field empty. Is that the info you were looking for?

I can reproduce the same issue when using Username and SSH private key on the SSH Service Connection. However, it can work fine when using Username and Password. You can consider using this way. @mr-woodapple

I can reproduce the same issue when using Username and SSH private key to configure the SSH Service Connection.
However, when using Username and Password to configure the connection, the task can work fine.
Looks likes, there are some issue on the task when using the SSH Service Connection with Username and SSH private key. You can try to open a ticket on Developer Community to report this issue. The support engineer on Developer Community would be help to report the issue to the appropriate product team for further investigation and fix.
And currently, as a workaround, you can try to use Username and Password to configure the SSH Service Connection.


Many thanks for your help, much appreciated! Have opened a ticket now, let's see what happens. :)

@mr-woodapple, Does it work for you when using Username and Password to configure the SSH Service Connection? If it works, you can consider this way as the workaround currently.

I've not tested that, the workaround I'm using now is letting the agent run on the live VM, as it's very low traffic volume anyway.

@mr-woodapple, If other steps in your pipeline job do not require running on a particular machine that is different than the live VM, it's okay to directly install the self-hosted agent on the live VM.
